# How to keep the value of an internal variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Is there a way in JavaScript to retain the value of a variable in a function?
In the function below, it now returns 1 every time it gets called. I'd like it to return 1, 2, 3, 4 etc on successive calls.

I know I can achieve that by declaring the i variable outside the function, but I don't want to pollute the global variable space with a variable that only get's used inside one function.

```
    function counter() {
        let i;
        if (!i) i = 0;
        i++;
        return i
    }
```

Comment: `const counter = (() => { let i; return () => { if (!i) ... }})()` — To adapt the duplicate above to your situation.

Comment: You may also find a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) useful for this particular example.